# Single word for : never accomplished anything in his life

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word to : 
what you can call a person that never accomplished anything in their life

Comment: I think that looking for synonyms of 'failure' could be considered general reference.

Answer (score 1):

How about 'ne'er-do-well'; it's a bit old fashioned but still works. Apparently that one line answer is deletable on the grounds of insufficient information, so to correct that I can dilate that ne'er-do-well is axiomatically a one letter contraction of 'never-do-well' which according to the O.E.D first appeared written in English in 1737 although 'ne'er' first appeared in 1275; their definition is 'one who never does and is never likely to do well, a good-for-nothing, worthless person'.Webster's Encyclopedic Dictionary says 'a worthless person likely to get into trouble' and Dr Johnson strangely does not have 'ne'er-do-well' but does define 'ne'er' as (for never) and gives this quote from Hudibras, a 17th century poem by Samuel Butler - "It appears I am no horse, That I can argue and discourse; Have but two legs and ne'er a tail"
I hope this will not be regarded as deletable on the grounds of prolixity or sesquipedalianism.

Comment: This would be a good answer with some supporting information.

Answer (score 1):

**Wastrel**

> [noun, literary]
>
> A person who does nothing positive with their life, making no use of their abilities or the opportunities that are offered to them.

[[Cambridge dictionary]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wastrel)

Answer (score 1):

**Non-achiever** (noun)

> • any person who does not succeed or progress, especially because of lack of interest or motivation. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nonachiever)

**Failure** (noun)

> • an unsuccessful person, enterprise, or thing. [(Google)](https://www.google.ca/search?rlz=1C2AOHY_enCA752CA752&q=define%3A%20a%20failure&oq=define%3A%20a%20failure&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l4.2111.6015.0.6459.19.18.1.0.0.0.185.1950.4j12.16.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.17.1947...0j0i131k1j0i67k1.ItjGCKwjeOM)

Answer (score 1):

**loser** is a common slang term for such a person. It is quite harsh in tone.

> loser
>
> 3. Slang. a misfit, especially someone who has never or seldom been successful at a job, personal relationship, etc.
>
> [[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/loser)]

Answer (score 1):

- Fruitless/Futile
- Non-achiever
- Impotent
- Useless
- Unsuccessful
- NEET (acronym for someone with no employment, education or training)
- etc.